Add "New Text Document" entry in the windows context menu
Note: this is NOT about Windows 11 but for Windows 10.
I want to add an entry in the right-click context menu which would create a new text document. I want that entry OUTSIDE the "New" section of the context menu.
To reiterate - NOT in "New >" but OUTSIDE it, where all the other entries in the context menu reside.
How can I do that?
